# Show indents for Spyder IDE

Tags: python, python-3.6, indentation, spyder

Is there a way to visualize tab indents in the Spyder?

I know I can visualize blank spaces under the 'Source' tab. For tabs, this now shows 4 dots.

It would be great if there was a way to show this as a single tab rather than 4 spaces.

Answer (score 4):

I'm pretty sure there are actually 4 spaces there. As per [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation), Python code should use 4 spaces for indentation, not a tab character. If you haven't changed your settings* in Spyder, it will insert 4 spaces when you press the tab key.

Spyder 4 will allow you to [mark indentation levels with vertical lines](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/pull/4572). It will hopefully be released in 2019. Or you can already download the first beta.

*The characters used for indentation could be changed by going to Tools/Preferences/Editor/Indentation characters. It should always be 4 spaces though.